# How to convert a handle string to a std::string

Tags: c++-cli

I am trying to convert a handle string to a normal string. I though the method I was using was working, but when I look in the debugger it appears that half of my string has been chopped off on the line that creates the chars variable. Any idea why and what the proper way to convert a handle string to a normal string woudl be?

```
std::string convert(String^ s) {
    const char* chars = (const char*)(System::Runtime::InteropServices::Marshal::
        StringToHGlobalAnsi(s)).ToPointer();
    string myNewString = std::string(chars);
    return myNewString;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably the debugger that's cutting off the display of the string. You didn't mention how long a string you're using, but the debugger can't display infinite length, so it has to cut it off at some point.

To verify this, try printing `myNewString` to the console, or to the debugger via [`Debug::WriteLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debug.writeline.aspx) or [`OutputDebugString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363362.aspx).

However, there is a significant issue in your code: After allocating memory with [`StringToHGlobalAnsi`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.stringtohglobalansi.aspx?cs-lang=cpp), you *must* free it using [`FreeHGlobal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.freehglobal.aspx?cs-lang=cpp).

If you want to continue using `StringToHGlobalAnsi`, I'd fix it up like this:

```
std::string convert(String^ s) {
    IntPtr ptr = Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(s);
    string myNewString = std::string((const char*)ptr.ToPointer());
    Marshal::FreeHGlobal(ptr);
    return myNewString;
}
```

However, it's probably easier to use the [`marshal_as`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384859.aspx) methods. This will take care of everything for you.

```
std::string output = marshal_as<std::string>(managedString);
```

Comment: Yes this is it. I am troubleshooting a problem that does not exist. :)